# How to pass values to vue data from laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I have a create product for and i want to fill customer_id hidden input using blade, but user can change it while he/she is on form page. How can i pass pre selected customer id to vue product data model? here is my code:

```
@section('content')
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="{{ $customer->id }}" v-model="product.customer" />
@endsection
```

This is my vue instance:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    product: {
        'customer': null,
        'title': null,
    }
},
```

This code will lead both customer in vue, and customer in input field to be null.

Comment: Have u got a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your data must return an object try this syntax:

```
data() {
    return {
      product: {
        customer: null,
        title: null,
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: app instance is my  main instance and i don't use template. I believe this is not the case.

Comment: mm, if your customer is object try initialize as en empty object `cusromer: {}`

Comment: another thing you need to have a **div** with an `id="app"` around your content

Comment: No, div is not solution. There is another html that i didn't write in sample code. Everything work fine unless fetching customer_id from blade to vue.

Comment: try to `@{{$customer->id}}` to prevent conflict between laravel and vuejs

Comment: $customer is a laravel model. I want to load this value to product.customer

Comment: Remove the `@` and check in google inspector to see the value of the hidden input if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Use props for that and don't forget to `json_encode($customer)` when you pass it to the component.

Comment: I didn't use component. If i use components, with props i can send variables from parent to child, here from instance to component, but i need reverse. I know i can use defining var in javascript and use it. but i prefer other way if exist.